# unable to load image from assets folder in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a big problem. I am Unable to load image onto canvas from assets folder in angular.

html code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 canvas-viewer">
            <canvas width="240" height="297" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;" id="crfCanvas" #crfCanvas></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 canvas-anno">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

component.ts code

```
export class CanvasComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild("crfCanvas", { static: true }) crfCanvas: ElementRef;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let canvas = this.crfCanvas.nativeElement;
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = "../../assets/aCRF-PRV111_CLN-001 v1.4-images/aCRF-PRV111_CLN-001 v1.4-blank_0.jpg";
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10, 250, 250);
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your angular.json file?

Comment: ok i will add to question

Comment: Also check the path of the image file in src

Comment: @Niladri,  not able to post angular.json file it has 120 lines of code,

Comment: You can post only the `assets` section

Comment: try with this path `./assets/aCRF-PRV111_CLN-001 v1.4-images/aCRF-PRV111_CLN-001 v1.4-blank_0.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things needs to be considered:

1. ViewChild binds to the view, so its best to await for the view to finish initialization (use ngAfterViewInit hook), but ngOnInit will also work (it is just if you would need in future to consider offsets etc for drawing into canvas it might bite you:)
2. Image loading is an async task, you need to leverage onload hook before you attempt to draw the image
3. Use "/assets/.." urls to avoid issues

Updated code:

```
export class CanvasComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild("crfCanvas", { static: true }) crfCanvas: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let canvas = this.crfCanvas.nativeElement;
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = "/assets/aCRF-PRV111_CLN-001 v1.4-images/aCRF-PRV111_CLN-001 v1.4-blank_0.jpg";
    img.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10, 250, 250);
    }
  }

}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5tqbn